# Define an index on a new array in a loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$chart_data = array();
foreach ($range as $range_day) {
  foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if($range_day == $number['date']){
      @$chart_data[$range_day] += $number['events'];
    } else {
      if(isset($chart_data[$range_day])){
        $chart_data[$range_day] += 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This line: `$chart_data[$range_day] += 0;` was giving me an undefined index error, so I added the `isset` check, but it's not set so it wrecks my array. I know that it's not set, and I don't care, but I read all over that the `@` solution is in poor taste. How can I remove the error the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set it to zero at the beginning:

```
$chart_data = array();
foreach ($range as $range_day) {
  $chart_data[$range_day] = 0;
  foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if($range_day == $number['date']){
      $chart_data[$range_day] += $number['events'];
    } else {
      if(isset($chart_data[$range_day])){
        $chart_data[$range_day] += 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would recommend also removing error suppression, since it is no longer "necessary" once you add the `isset()` check.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the `array_key_exists` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php ?

Something like:

```
$chart_data = array();
foreach ($range as $range_day) {
  foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if(!array_key_exists($range_day, $array)) {
      $chart_data[$range_day] = 0;
    }
    if($range_day == $number['date']){
      $chart_data[$range_day] += $number['events'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would recommend also removing error suppression, since it's no longer "necessary" once you add the `array_key_exists()` check.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it's **not** set, then set it:

```
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if (!isset($chart_data[$range_day])) {
        $chart_data[$range_day] = 0;
    }
    if ($range_day == $number['date']) {
        $chart_data[$range_day] += $number['events'];
    } else {
        $chart_data[$range_day] += 0; // you're just adding 0 so why have this line at all?
    }
}
```

This answers assumes that there is the possibility that `$range` could contain a duplicate `$range_day` and so it won't overwrite the corresponding element in `$chart_data`.